# Cannot work around the error TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataset looks like this which is fairly large.

[image: sample dataset]

I am trying to write this data to different data frames each corresponding to Fullbacks, Center Backs etc.

So far I have this:

```
def get_dataset(f):
    return pd.read_csv(f)


def split(dataset):
    names = dataset.Categories.str.extract(r'([^>]*>[^>]*)').drop_duplicates().values.tolist()
    splitframes = [dataset[dataset['Categories'].str.contains(name)] for name in names]
    for splitframe in splitframes:
        splitframe.to_csv(splitframe.name + '.csv')

def main(file):
    dataset = get_dataset(file)
    split(dataset)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('infile', nargs=1, type=argparse.FileType('r'))

    args = parser.parse_args()

    main(*args.infile)
```

I cannot find my way out of this error which says  -- > TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
Appreciate helping me figure out what is wrong with what I am trying to do and get around this.

Comment: On which line do you get the error? Have you tried running your code with a debugger?

Comment: splitframes = [dataset[dataset['Categories'].str.contains(name)] for name in names]

Comment: Seems to me like name is a list instead of a string. So names would be List[List[str]] intead of List[str].